# Context table showing backticks

Tags: tables, context

I am trying to make a table but backticks are shown. Here is the code:

```
\starttext

\startplacetable[title={Traits of Layer. Here are some desirable traits of layers.},list={Traits of Layer}]
\setuptables[rulethickness=0.03em, width=4.4in]
\starttable[s0|lp(0.35\textwidth)|xp(0.55\textwidth)|]
  \HL[2]
  \NC {\bf Trait} \NC {\bf Descriptions} \NC \AR
  \HL[1]
  \NC Egg production \NC Number of eggs; in-cage production; and percentage of hen-day \NC \AR
  \NC Egg weight \NC Weight and size of egg; and egg shape index \NC \AR
  \NC Egg quality - external \NC Strength; thickness; color and shape; porosity of shell \NC \AR
  \HL[2]
\stoptable
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

The pdf shows something like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not you.

It seems that line 61 in `tabl-tab.mkxl` has the extra back tick. It will be removed in the next release. What you can do to fix it now is to remove it from the file and then run

```
context --make
```

to regenerate the format. Then it will go.

Comment: There should be a new version out now.